# Is it possible to unload built-in kernel module?

Tags: kernel

I have a kernel with built-in module that I want to replace. I have built a .ko and tried to insmod it, but it failed since the kernel was already built with it.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure so I'm not giving this as an answer - but can't you do it with `rmmod <module name>`?

Comment: This works with .ko only modules, and not builtin modules. builtin modules don't show up in lsmod.

Comment: AFAIK what's built-in cannot be "rmod'ed". But that's not an Android specific question (rather a Linux/Unix generic one), so you might wish to check with those "stacks" (they might even have that question already answered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Built-in drivers aren't modules, they are built-in (hence the name). If it's not showing in lsmod, you can't get rid of it short of building a new kernel.